# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python-3.x

When I run code below, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

But I don't know where is `dtype('O')` and `dtype('int64')`. Does anyone know where is to parse?

```
import collections 
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd

def pre_prob(y):
    y_dict = collections.Counter(y)
    pre_probab = np.ones(2)
    for i in range(0, 2):
        pre_probab[i] = y_dict[i]/y.shape[0]
    return pre_probab

def mean_var(X, y):
    n_features = X.shape[1]
    m = np.ones((2, n_features))
    v = np.ones((2, n_features))
    n_0 = np.bincount(y)[np.nonzero(np.bincount(y))[0]][0]
    x0 = np.ones((n_0, n_features))
    x1 = np.ones((X.shape[0] - n_0, n_features))

    k = 0
    for i in range(0, X.shape[0]):
        if y[i] == 0:
            x0[k] = X[i]
            k = k + 1
        k = 0
    for i in range(0, X.shape[0]):
        if y[i] == 1:
            x1[k] = X[i]
            k = k + 1
    for j in range(0, n_features):
        m[0][j] = np.mean(x0.T[j])
        v[0][j] = np.var(x0.T[j])*(n_0/(n_0 - 1))
        m[1][j] = np.mean(x1.T[j])
        v[1][j] = np.var(x1.T[j])*((X.shape[0]-n_0)/((X.shape[0]- n_0) - 1))
    return m, v # mean and variance

def prob_feature_class(m, v, x):
    n_features = m.shape[1]
    pfc = np.ones(2)
    for i in range(0, 2):
        product = 1
        for j in range(0, n_features):
            product = product * (1/math.sqrt(2*3.14*v[i][j])) * math.exp(-0.5* pow((x[j] - m[i][j]),2)/v[i][j])
        pfc[i] = product
    return pfc

def GNB(X, y, x):
    m, v = mean_var(X, y)
    pfc = prob_feature_class(m, v, x)
    pre_probab = pre_prob(y)
    pcf = np.ones(2)
    total_prob = 0
    for i in range(0, 2):
        total_prob = total_prob + (pfc[i] * pre_probab[i])
    for i in range(0, 2):
        pcf[i] = (pfc[i] * pre_probab[i])/total_prob
    prediction = int(pcf.argmax())
    return m, v, pre_probab, pfc, pcf, prediction
```

Comment: If you can provide the line on which the error is occurring and the values of any variables it would make it easier to help

Comment: I guess on this line n_0 = np.bincount(y)[np.nonzero(np.bincount(y))[0]][0]